# Unity Webapp not working with Chromium (13.04)

Tags: unity, 13.04, chromium, webapps

I usually use the Unity Webapps integration with Chromium, but today after an fresh Ubuntu intallation the webapps doesn't work.

What can I do to make an log of it or something like that to find out?

Answer (score 1):

You need the desktop integration package:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-service

sudo apt-get install unity-chromium-extension
```

Reboot or log out and then back in and it should work.

If you allow a webapp for notifications,it will show in dconf:

[image]